# Google Sign in doesn't work in Signed APK

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I have integrated a google sign in into my application. when I test by USB debugging, it seems  to work fine on multiple devices, the google sign in works fine, because the user can access the application. When I create a signed apk, with V1 and V2 signing, nobody can authenticate with the server, not even me, who created the authentication link in the first place.

this is the code responsible for the authentication:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private LinearLayout prof_section;
private Button SignOut;
private SignInButton SignIn;
private TextView Name,Email;
private ImageView Prof_Picture;
private Button continueBut;
String personName;
private static final int REQ_CODE = 9001;
String name;
Intent nameSave;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

public static final String prefsName = "com.personal.mayankthakur.myapplication";


private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(com.personal.mayankthakur.myapplication.R.layout.activity_main);

    prof_section = (LinearLayout) findViewById(com.personal.mayankthakur.myapplication.R.id.prof_section);
    SignOut = (Button) findViewById(com.personal.mayankthakur.myapplication.R.id.logoutBtn);
    SignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(com.personal.mayankthakur.myapplication.R.id.gSignIn);
    Name = (TextView) findViewById(com.personal.mayankthakur.myapplication.R.id.nameSpace);
    Email = (TextView) findViewById(com.personal.mayankthakur.myapplication.R.id.emailSpace);
    Prof_Picture = (ImageView) findViewById(com.personal.mayankthakur.myapplication.R.id.profilePicture);
    continueBut = (Button) findViewById(com.personal.mayankthakur.myapplication.R.id.button2);
    continueBut.setOnClickListener(this);
    SignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
    SignIn.setOnClickListener(this) ;
    prof_section.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    continueBut.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();


}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed (@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult){

}
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, REQ_CODE );
}
private void signOut(){

    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
            updateUI(false);
        }
    });

}
private void handleReuslt(GoogleSignInResult result){

    if(result.isSuccess())
    {
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        personName = acct.getDisplayName();

        // This is the shared preference
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefsName, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        //adding a value to the preference
        prefs.putString("personName", personName);
        prefs.apply();

        String personEmail = acct.getEmail();

        // This is the shared preference
        SharedPreferences.Editor emailPrefs = getSharedPreferences(prefsName, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        //adding a value to the preference
        emailPrefs.putString("personEmail", personEmail);
        emailPrefs.apply();

        String imgUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
        Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
        Name.setText(personName);
        Email.setText(personEmail);
        Glide.with(this).load(imgUrl).into(Prof_Picture);
        updateUI(true);
    }
    else
    {
        updateUI(false);
    }

}
private void updateUI(boolean isLogin){

    if(isLogin)
    {
        prof_section.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        SignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        continueBut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    else
    {
        prof_section.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        SignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == REQ_CODE)
    {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleReuslt(result);
    }


}
@Override
public void onClick (View v) {


    switch (v.getId()) {

        case com.personal.mayankthakur.myapplication.R.id.gSignIn:
            signIn();

            break;

        case com.personal.mayankthakur.myapplication.R.id.logoutBtn:
            signOut();

            break;
        case com.personal.mayankthakur.myapplication.R.id.button2:

            nameSave = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(nameSave);
    }


}
}
```

this is my first time trying to publish an app to google play, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you get any error message on the console?

Comment: Did you add the release key store signature to the developer console?

Answer (score 0):

Was your `build variant` `debug` because it must be set to `release`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the SHA-1 checksum of the release key in the firebase/google console.

First generate key using following command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore KEYSTORE_PATH -alias ALIAS_NAME
```

Then copy the SHA-1 checksum and go to:

> Firebase Console > Your project > Settings of the app > Add Fingerprint

Then save the checksum and you are good to go.